# SUMIFS spilled range between certain dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I'm building an inventory history that will grow throughout the year and include new products. I don't want my formula to look past the date the product went live.

For example: Product was launched and had inventory on 5/4/2021, I don't want to see all of the 0's on the days previous. I'm using 365, I have my initial attempt at this below.

```
=SUMIFS(history[quantity],history[sku],S5:S8,history[date],U3#,history[disposition],S2,history[date],">="&G4,history[date],"<="&S3)
```

- U3# = a spilled range of dates from 5/4/2020 to the current day
- G4 = the date the product was launched
- S3 = a cell that references todays date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(date < ProductLaunchDate, "", SUMIFS(...))
```

Comment: Explaining how this solves the problem will go a long way towards making it a better answer.